# Load Bitmap from JSON android without Async Task

Tags: android, json, bitmap, android-asynctask

i want to ask for Android, i have JSON and i want to load it into Grid View or List View . I already convert my JSON (base64) into Bitmap and load it with AsyncTask, but it really Slow because i Load all the JSON first and then Show it .Actually i don't want to load it first then show all the JSON. i want load it one by one. so i am not wait it too long. 
what can i use ?

here my example Code ;

```
 private class GetImageProduct extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Object>{

        @Override
        protected Objects doInBackground(String... params) {
            String productCode = params[0];
            String skuCode = params[1];
            String productImageUrl = ""+urlProduct+"?filter={\"where\":{\"Code\":\""+ productCode +"\"}}";
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
            String jsonString = sh.makeServiceCall(productImageUrl);
            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonString);

            if(jsonString != null){
                try{
                    JSONArray productDetails = new JSONArray(jsonString);
                    for(int j=0 ;j<productDetails.length();j++){

                        JSONObject q = productDetails.getJSONObject(j);
                        String productImage = q.getString("Image");
                        String productName = q.getString("Name");
                        String encodeImage = productImage.replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,","").replace("data:image/png;base64,","");
                        byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(encodeImage,Base64.DEFAULT);
                        Bitmap base64Bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString,0,decodedString.length);
                        Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(base64Bitmap, 1000,1000,true);

                        HashMap<String, Object> productData = new HashMap<String,Object>();
                        productData.put("base64Bitmap",resized );
                        productData.put("productName",productName);
                        imageList.add(productData);


                    }
                }catch(final JSONException e){
                    Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (pDialog.isShowing()) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }


            ExtendedSimpleAdapterMapping adapter2 = new ExtendedSimpleAdapterMapping(
                    MappingProductActivity.this, imageList,
                    R.layout.list_selected_product,
                    new String[]{"base64Bitmap","productName"},
                    new int[]{R.id.imageSelId, R.id.txtProductName}
            );
            lv.setAdapter(adapter2);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not good approach , You have to return only imagename from server , and concatenate it with your url like `http://localhost/images/yourimage.jpg`

For Sending image from Android to PHP and store it in files in server check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45592155/3872374)

Comment: i already have data base64 from API . i just want to load it . but it really slow because of asynctask. i want to load it first when one of data loaded. so, i must change the type of data ? from base64 to Url in database?

Comment: do you face problem in loading bitmap image ??

Comment: no . i can load it very well , but it takes long time , because the whole data must be load first then the adapter display it.

Comment: no, i am not used it. i just convert the base64 to bitmap and load it after the do..background done and the adapter displayed it . but , the problem is the do..background is very slow because the looping to get and convert base64 from API.